# Using getResources in a class constructor causes to crash

Tags: android, constructor, android-resources

I have a class constructor. inside that I want to use string resources using getResources.
when I want to run the app it produces an error tells "Unfortunately myProject has stopped".

```
    public EhsanAdapter(Context c) {
            context = c;
            size = 5;
            list = new ArrayList<SingleRow>();

            Resources res = c.getResources();
    }
```

What's wrong with this? when I comment the line with getresource command, I have no error.

This is whole class:

```
package com.example.listviewba;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

class SingleRow{
    String title;
    String description;
    int image;

    public SingleRow(String title,String description,int image) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description=description;
        this.image=image;
    }
}

public class EhsanAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    Context context;
    int size;
    ArrayList<SingleRow> list;


    public EhsanAdapter(Context c) {
        context = c;
        size = 5;
        list = new ArrayList<SingleRow>();
        Resources res = c.getResources();
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return 0;
    }

    public void addView(){
        size++;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        RowView view = null;

        if (convertView == null){
            view = new RowView(this.context);
        }
        else{
            view = (RowView) convertView;
        }
        view.setLeftText("Shit");
        view.setRightText("Fuck");
        return view;
    }

}
```

and this is how I'm calling the class:

```
package com.example.listviewba;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EhsanAdapter adapter = new EhsanAdapter(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: What does the logcrash say? Looks like "c" could be null.

Comment: It tells "Unfortunately myProject has stopped"

Comment: Could you please post your logcat? Thanks.

Comment: Resources.getSystem().getString(android.R.string.yourstring) use this .

Comment: @Carnal you can see my code. nothing is null.

Comment: @fasteque There are tens of lines of codes. What should I post?

Comment: @user1920666 not worked man! I want to access my strings inside string.xml. I think your solution is for system strings.

Comment: search for an exception in your log filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `EhsanAdapter adapter = new EhsanAdapter(this);` down like this:

```
final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);
EhsanAdapter adapter = new EhsanAdapter(this);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

You can't declare it before `onCreate` because your `Context` will be `null` at this time.

Or if you want your `EhsanAdapter` to be an instance variable, you can declare it in the class like `private EhsanAdapter adapter;`

and in `onCreate` you initiate like `adapter = new EhsanAdapter(this);`